# Backing encrypted drive

Tags: libvirt, qemu

Creating a backing image for the master image that is encrypted using LUKS:

```bash
qemu-img create -f qcow2 -b dev.qcow2 -F qcow2 -o encrypt.format=luks,encrypt.key-secret=dev --object secret,id=dev,data='same_as_for_dev.qcow2' dev-inc.qcow2
```

libvirt configuration:

```xml
<disk type="file" device="disk">
  <driver name="qemu" type="qcow2" cache="unsafe"/>
  <source file="/home/user/qemu/dev-inc.qcow2"/>
  <target dev="vda" bus="virtio"/>
  <encryption format="luks" engine="qemu">
    <secret type="passphrase" uuid="0a81f5b2-8403-7b23-c8d6-21ccc2f80d6f"/>
  </encryption>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x08" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</disk>
```

getting this error:

```
Error starting domain: internal error: Unexpected enum value 0 for virStorageEncryptionEngine

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 72, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 108, in tmpcb
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/libvirtobject.py", line 57, in newfn
    ret = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/domain.py", line 1384, in startup
    self._backend.create()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 1353, in create
    raise libvirtError('virDomainCreate() failed')
libvirt.libvirtError: internal error: Unexpected enum value 0 for virStorageEncryptionEngine
```

Is it possible to crate a backing image for the encrypted qcow2, if yes, then what am I missing?

Comment: in libvirt config what is cache="unsafe" doing?

Comment: Is it related to my question? I need max possible disk performance.

Comment: I just dont see that in the libvirt configuration options, i'd try it without that.

Comment: Try it with Cache=none

Comment: Getting the same error